# UIAnimation based on AVAudioPlayer's peakPowerForChannel

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, alpha, uianimation

I would like to animate the alpha of an png image in a `UIImageView` based on the peakPowerForChannel of `AVAudioPlayer`. I haven't got any errors or crashes, but its not working. Here are (what I believe) the relevant parts of my ViewController code:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property(getter = isMeteringEnabled) BOOL meteringEnabled;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *mouthMeter;
- (void)updateMouthMeter:(id) sender;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{ 
... 
self.meterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self       selector:@selector(updateMouthMeter:) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];
}

-(void)updateMouthMeter : (id)sender {
[self.audioPlayer updateMeters];
float level = [self.audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:0];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
self.mouthMeter.alpha = level;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I think my problem lies in the fact the `AVAudioPlayer` outputs a MAX of 0.0dB and a MIN of -160dB, and I need to process this input so that it outputs a float (0.0 to 1.0) suitable for the alpha channel.

Any suggestions on how I can do this? Can it be included in the above updateMouthMeter method?

Comment: I might be wrong, but that's some simple math? value x = 1.0 / (160 - (MIN_DB * -1)) -> x equals the value for the alpha channel

Comment: @Swissdude ok! so because it's giving me the peak (MAX dB) I've got this going on:  _float level = [self.audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:0];
    float alphaLevel = ((level * -1.0)/160);_  and it's giving me positive float numbers in the 0. to -1 range, however there is a distinct peak in volume everytime the NSTimer updates the UIView alpha.... hm..

Answer (score 0):

This has morphed into a problem with NSTimer and  updating UIAnimations. I have 2 NSTimers in my ViewController: One of them, *sliderTimer* ,updates a progress slider at an interval of 1.0 (1 sec). The other,  *meterTimer*, updates the UIAnimation of an alpha channel in UIView. The *sliderTimer*  seems to be interferring with *meterTimer*.
In the simulator, it creates a blinking effect in my animation and in the log there is a repetitive peak in the float number at of the top each second. Here's the relevant parts of my code:
    .h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *mouthMeter;
- (void)updateSlider:(id) sender;<br/>
- (void)updateMouthMeter:(id) sender;
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
....
self.sliderTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateSlider:) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];
self.meterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateMouthMeter:) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];
}

-(void)updateSlider : (id)sender {
//Update progressSlider about the music time
self.circularSliderPlayback.value = self.audioPlayer.currentTime;
}

-(void)updateMouthMeter : (id)sender {
[self.audioPlayer updateMeters];
float level = [self.audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:0];
float alphaLevel = ((level * -1.0)/160);

NSLog(@"this is the alphaLevel %f",alphaLevel);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
self.mouthMeter.alpha = alphaLevel;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I'm new to iOS programming, is it a total no-no to have 2 NSTimers going in the same .m file? What are my options to get rid of this pulsing effect from *sliderTimer*?
 Also, i've noticed *sliderTimer* is also affecting the audio being played back.. there is a quick pause at each second. What's goin' on?

Comment: try averagePowerForChannel instead of peakPowerForChannel

Comment: @Swissdude Alright, changed it... still seem to have the issue. I think this is a new question now. Will post it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526084/nstimer-creating-a-pulse-effect-in-avaudioplayer-and-uianimation